# "org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null];

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, hibernate

i am traying to save a data in my data basewith a postmethod but i dont know why he said that one of my value is null (is_in_a_warehouse).
Is my json the problem ?
If i delete the "boolean not null" it will works but the value of is_in_a_warehouse will be null even if i put false in my json date
I am really sorry for my bad english and thx for your help guys

```
GET http://localhost:8080/api/v8/freights
Accept: application/json

###

POST http://localhost:8080/api/v8/freights
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json

{
   "name" : " nom",
   "is_in_a_warehouse" : false,
   "company":{
       "name" : "compaNom",
       "address" :{
           "city": "pays",
           "country":"ville",
           "street" : "rue",
           "number" : 1
       }
   }
}

###
```

```
CREATE TABLE freight( 
    id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    is_in_a_warehouse  BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
    company_id int8 NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT fk_company FOREIGN KEY (company_id) REFERENCES company (id)

);

CREATE TABLE freight_mouvement (
  freight_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  mouvement_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT fk_freight_mvt_freight FOREIGN KEY (freight_id) REFERENCES freight (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_freight_mvt_mvt FOREIGN KEY (mouvement_id) REFERENCES mouvement (id),
  CONSTRAINT pk_freight_mvt PRIMARY KEY (freight_id, mouvement_id)
);
```

```
@RestController
public class FreightController {
    @Autowired
    private FreightRepository  freightRepository;
    @Autowired
    private AddressRepository  addressRepository;
    @Autowired
    private CompanyRepository  companyRepository;
  
    @GetMapping("/api/v8/freights")
    public List<Freight> listfreights() {
      return (List<Freight>) freightRepository.findAll();
    }
  
    @PostMapping("/api/v8/freights")
    public void createFreight(@RequestBody Freight freight) {
      addressRepository.save(freight.getCompany().getAddress());
      companyRepository.save(freight.getCompany());
      freightRepository.save(freight);
    }
    
}
```

the message error

```
HTTP/1.1 500 
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Fri, 20 May 2022 02:55:37 GMT
Connection: close

{
  "timestamp": "2022-05-20T02:55:37.741+00:00",
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "trace": "org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:276)\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:233)\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:566)\n\tat org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:743)\n\tat org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:711)\n\tat org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:654)\n\tat org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:407)\n\tat org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\n\tat org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\n\tat org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:174)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)\n\tat com.sun.proxy.$Proxy454.save(Unknown Source)\n\tat be.eafcuccle.projint.backend.LucaLi06.rest.FreightController.createFreight(FreightController.java:29)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:96)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)\n\tat org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1743)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)\nCaused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement\n\tat org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:59)\n\tat org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:37)\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:200)\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:46)\n\tat org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3375)\n\tat org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3908)\n\tat org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:107)\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604)\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.lambda$executeActions$1(ActionQueue.java:478)\n\tat java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:684)\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:475)\n\tat org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:344)\n\tat org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:40)\n\tat org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107)\n\tat org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1407)\n\tat org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:489)\n\tat org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3290)\n\tat org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2425)\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:449)\n\tat org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:183)\n\tat org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$300(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:40)\n\tat org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:281)\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:101)\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:562)\n\t... 69 more\nCaused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: NULL not allowed for column \"IS_IN_A_WAREHOUSE\"; SQL statement:\ninsert into freight (company_id, is_in_a_warehouse, name, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?) [23502-200]\n\tat org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:459)\n\tat org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:429)\n\tat org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:205)\n\tat org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:181)\n\tat org.h2.table.Column.validateConvertUpdateSequence(Column.java:374)\n\tat org.h2.table.Table.validateConvertUpdateSequence(Table.java:845)\n\tat org.h2.command.dml.Insert.insertRows(Insert.java:187)\n\tat org.h2.command.dml.Insert.update(Insert.java:151)\n\tat org.h2.command.CommandContainer.update(CommandContainer.java:198)\n\tat org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:251)\n\tat org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:191)\n\tat org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:152)\n\tat com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61)\n\tat com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:197)\n\t... 90 more\n",
  "message": "could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement",
  "path": "/api/v8/freights"
```

edit :

```
@Entity
public class Freight {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;

    private String name;
    private Boolean is_in_a_warehouse;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "company_id")
    private Company company;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "freight_mouvement", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "freight_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "mouvement_id"))
    private Set<Mouvement> mouvements = new HashSet<>();

    protected Freight() {
    }

    public Freight(String name, Boolean is_in_a_warehouse, Company company) {
        this.setName(name);
        this.setInAWarehouse(is_in_a_warehouse);
        this.company = company;
    }

    public Boolean isInAWarehouse() {
        return is_in_a_warehouse;
    }

    public void setInAWarehouse(Boolean isInAWarehouse) {
        this.is_in_a_warehouse = isInAWarehouse;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Company getCompany(){
        return company;
    }
    
    public Long getId(){
        return id;
    }

    public Set<Mouvement> getSessions() {
        return mouvements;
    }
  
    public void addMouvement(Mouvement mouvement) {
      mouvements.add(mouvement);
    }
  
    
}
```

edit v2

```
@Entity
public class Freight {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;

    private String name;
    
    @Column(name="is_in_a_warehouse")
    private Boolean isInAWarehouse;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "company_id")
    private Company company;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "freight_mouvement", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "freight_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "mouvement_id"))
    private Set<Mouvement> mouvements = new HashSet<>();

    protected Freight() {
    }

    public Freight(String name, Boolean is_in_a_warehouse, Company company) {
        this.setName(name);
        this.setInAWarehouse(is_in_a_warehouse);
        this.company = company;
    }

    public Boolean isInAWarehouse() {
        return isInAWarehouse;
    }

    public void setInAWarehouse(Boolean isInAWarehouse) {
        this.isInAWarehouse = isInAWarehouse;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Company getCompany(){
        return company;
    }
    
    public Long getId(){
        return id;
    }

    public Set<Mouvement> getSessions() {
        return mouvements;
    }
  
    public void addMouvement(Mouvement mouvement) {
      mouvements.add(mouvement);
    }
  
    
}
```

Comment: Does your backend expect camelCase keys and you are sending snake_case? Try changing the json key from is_in_a_warehouse to isInAWarehouse.

Comment: Already tried but it doesn't change anything my backed doesn't except camCase for this one

Comment: Can you add the source code for the Freight class?

Comment: sure i edited my post

Comment: I still think it's most likely a mapping issue, try changing the variable name to isInAWarehouse and the getter and setter to getIsInAWarehouse and setIsInAWarehouse and send the key in camelCase.

Comment: Do you mean like my edit v2 ? i tried with this it still doesnt work